# Golang create gif animation from png images

Tags: go, animated-gif

I'm trying to create GIF animation from png images. But I get it with color Noise. Screenshot :https://prnt.sc/22rrrfn

I have tried to change Pallete.Plan9 because 256 colors maybe not enough but didn't get good results.

```golang
func test() error {
    fmt.Printf("Generating GIF")
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir("text")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var filenames []string
    for _, file := range files {
        filenames = append(filenames, file.Name())
    }

    anim := gif.GIF{LoopCount: len(filenames)}
    fmt.Println(anim.LoopCount)
    for _, filename := range filenames {
        reader, err := os.Open("text/" + filename)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error Open dir")
        }
        defer reader.Close()

        img, err := png.Decode(reader)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error Decode")
        }
        bounds := img.Bounds()
        drawer := draw.FloydSteinberg

        palettedImg := image.NewPaletted(bounds, palette.Plan9)

        drawer.Draw(palettedImg, img.Bounds(), img, image.ZP)
        anim.Image = append(anim.Image, palettedImg)
        anim.Delay = append(anim.Delay, 0)
    }
    output := fmt.Sprintf("FINAL.gif")
    file, err := os.Create(output)
    defer file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error create file")
    }
    encodeErr := gif.EncodeAll(file, &anim)
    if encodeErr != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Unable to create file %s: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, not entirely sure, but `drawer := draw.FloydSteinberg` uses Floyd-Steinberg dithering and might be creating those artifacts. Have you tried just using `draw.Draw`?

Would swap out this:

```golang
drawer := draw.FloydSteinberg

palettedImg:= image.NewPaletted(bounds, palette.Plan9)

drawer.Draw(palettedImg,img.Bounds(),img,image.ZP)
```

With this:

```golang
palettedImg:= image.NewPaletted(bounds, palette.Plan9)

draw.Draw(palettedImg,img.Bounds(),img,image.ZP)
```

And see what it looks like then.

Comment: `draw.Draw(palettedImg,img.Bounds(),img,image.ZP)` - not enough arguments
I have tried `draw.Draw(palettedImg,img.Bounds(),img,image.ZP, draw.Src)` and no dots but lack of colors and terrible gradient  https://prnt.sc/22s5lwh

Comment: Floyd-Steinberg  makes artifacts but Image with good colors and doesn't have gradient issue. Only issue with dots.
Maybe I can use another method not FloydSteinberg but I don't know what to use instead.